# Spring Cloud Stream can't create queue and binding

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream

First - I'm new to Spring Cloud Stream. I have a problem to crate one queue and binding between exchange and that queue using Cloud Spring Stream (3.2.1) and RabbitMQ

Application properties looks like (for not working part):

```
spring: 
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: directSmtpGatewayMessageInput;directStaProcessorInput;directStaPostProcessInput;directSmtpRemoteDeliveryInput;directXDDeliveryInput

    stream: 
      source: direct-smtp-gateway-message;direct-smtp-remote-delivery;direct-sta-processor;direct-sta-post-process;direct-sta-last-mile;direct-xd-delivery
    
      bindings: 

        direct-xd-delivery-out-0: 
          destination: direct-xd-delivery-process          
          
        directXDDeliveryInput-in-0: 
          destination: direct-xd-delivery-process  
          group: direct-xd-delivery-process-group
          consumer:
            concurrency: 10
            maxAttempts: 5
            backOffInitialInterval: 360000
            backOffMaxInterval: 92160000
            backOffMultiplier: 4
```

Stream Bridge:

```
@Component
public class XDRemoteDeliverySource
{
    protected static final String OUT_BINDING_NAME = "direct-xd-delivery-out-0";
    
    @Autowired
    private StreamBridge streamBridge;
    
    public <T> void xdRemoteDelivery(SMTPMailMessage msg) 
    {
        streamBridge.send(OUT_BINDING_NAME, SMTPMailMessageConverter.toStreamMessage(msg));
    }
}
```

Consumer (as a stream processor):

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class XDRemoteDeliveryProcessor implements XDDeliveryCallback
{
    @Autowired
    protected XDDeliveryCore deliveryCore;
    
    @Autowired
    protected SmtpGatewayMessageSource smtpMessageSource;
    
    @Autowired
    protected DSNCreator dsnCreator;
    
    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<?>> directXDDeliveryInput()
    {
        return streamMsg -> 
        {
            try
            {
               final SMTPMailMessage smtpMessage = SMTPMailMessageConverter.fromStreamMessage(streamMsg);

               deliveryCore.processAndDeliverXDMessage(smtpMessage);
            }
            catch (MessagingException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

I see message going to the `direct-xd-delivery-process` exchange and then, if I will create queue manually and bind it to the exchange as `direct-xd-delivery-process.direct-xd-delivery-process-group`, I will see message in the queue but for consumer still will not pick it up.

So my question is why defined consumer will not create queue and assigned binding as well will not pick up message from there if queue was created manually.

PS.
RabbitMQ:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`function.definition` should be under `spring.cloud` not `spring.cloud.stream`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_overview

**EDIT**

I just copied your YAML into a new Boot application and it works fine for me.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So70250552Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So70250552Application.class, args);
    }

}

@Configuration
class XDRemoteDeliveryProcessor {

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<?>> directXDDeliveryInput() {
        return System.out::println;
    }

}
```

[image]

Are you sure that `@Configuration` class is picked up by Boot - is it in the right package?

Comment: I will check that. Also it is interesting because all other input definitions from there are working fine just not `directXDDeliveryInput`

Comment: OK, moved under `spring.cloud` (OP updated as well) did not solved my problem - `directXDDeliveryInput` still will not crate a queue.

Comment: I just copied your YAML to a new Boot app and it works fine for me. See the edit.

Comment: I have updated OP with RabbitMQ screenshots. Also not sure about it the Boot picked up annotation. I have pulled that code from the GitHub. Consumer is here: https://github.com/DirectProjectJavaRI/xdmail/blob/develop/src/main/java/org/nhind/xd/streams/processors/XDRemoteDeliveryProcessor.java and is used by https://github.com/DirectProjectJavaRI/direct-sta-sboot/tree/develop

Comment: Should `org.nhind.xd.streams` be listed in `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.nhindirect.gateway.springconfig", "org.nhindirect.gateway.streams", "org.nhind.xdm.springconfig"})` ?

Comment: Yes, of course. By default, Boot only scans the package the `@SpringBootApplication` is in (and sub-packages).

Comment: OK, solved the problem. It was in the main Spring Boot app. Thanks for all those tips where to look at :)